# Get StreamCorruptedException when I try to read cripted object from a file

Tags: java, android, file-io, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

When I try to read a cripted Object stored in a file, apparently everything seems work **and I can get the saved value** , but in the log appears always this error

```
 java.io.StreamCorruptedException
W/System.err﹕ at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
W/System.err﹕ at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:372)
```

And I don't understod how to fix it

I use this to load:

```
ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(cipherInputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (inputStream != null) {

            try {
                myDecipheredObject = (Serializable) inputStream.readObject();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and this to store

```
 ObjectOutputStream outputStream = null;
            try {
                outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(cipherOutputStream);
                outputStream.writeObject(object);
                outputStream.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The error happens in this line of load method

```
inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(cipherInputStream);
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to create your cipher's input and output streams?

Comment: I use the same code of the cipher used here in various other methods but this error happens only here, so I'm almost certain that the cause of the issue is another.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible cause of the exception that I can think of, at the line you specified, is this:

When you construct a new ObjectInputStream from another InputStream, the constructor tries to read a header from the other InputStream. If it can't read and verify this header, it throws the StreamCorrupted Exception. This would happen if it cannot read the header, or if the header was wrong (for instance, contained a different magic number or version number).

Is it possible that the corresponding output stream was not in fact created before the input stream tried to read from it? Or that two different threads each tried to read from cipherOutputStream?

If the writing of the object takes a long time, it might be worth flushing the outputStream directly after constructing it, so that at least the header gets written immediately:

```
            outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(cipherOutputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.writeObject(object);
            outputStream.close();
```

Finally, I'm assuming that you're using the same key to decrypt as you used to encrypt. If not, then this could cause the header to be decrypted wrongly.